# How do I select more than one column within a data.frame which are not sequent?

Tags: r

Say I want to choose Column 1, 2, 3 and 4. I will type 1:4
.... Example:

> paste0('X__', 1:4)

How do I do this, if I want to choose 1,2,3 and 10?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: df[, c(1,2,3,10)]

Comment: Try this `df[,c(1,2,3,10)]`

Comment: Similar to Bill O'Brien: `df[,c(1:3, 10)]`

Comment: Thanks to all three! Is there any other way? I need to use this for some other calculations and one of them doesn't work with the result of it :/